# Goland: How to use a custom modfile instead of go.mod?

Tags: go, go-modules, goland

My project consists of multiple go modules which I need to work on simultaneously. This is made easy by using the `replace` directive in the go.mod file.

Further, in order to prevent this change from getting accidentally checked in, the go tools (starting with version 1.14) offer a `-modfile` switch which lets me put the `replace` directive in a `go.local.mod` file instead. This is super convenient.

**Unfortunately, I am unable to get Goland to pick up this `go.local.mod` instead of `go.mod`.**

I have tried setting the GOMOD environment variable under `Preferences -> Go -> Go Modules` to point to my `go.local.mod` file. This did not do what I expected it to (which is to use the `go.local.mod` file instead of `go.mod`)
Not surprisingly, this did not work since GOMOD is supposed to be readonly (as pointed out to me in the comments).

For now I can go back to putting the replace directive in the go.mod file and using commit hooks to prevent accidental check-in (and Goland has some tooling to perform this check as well) However, it would be super convenient if Goland can recognize this new -modfile switch that go has added. Figured I would ask to make sure I'm not missing something  obvious here.

Thanks!

Comment: You're right. Its not. But there is an "OTHER" option while setting env variables. So I tried it. Honestly, I don't really care if this is achieved using the GOMOD env-var. I'd just appreciate a way to do this, is all.

Comment: `GOMOD` is specifically documented as not being read from the environment. Are you looking for the `GOFLAGS` variable perhaps?

Comment: Apologies. Let me edit my question to remove the focus on GOMOD. 
What I am trying to achieve is to get Goland to use a different go.mod file than the default (i.e. the equivalent of the -modfile switch in go tooling)

Comment: I haven't tried it, but what about adding -modfile in the "Run Configuration"?

Comment: Did you try `GOFLAGS`? Does `GOFLAGS=-modfile=./go.local.mod` do what you want?

Comment: Just tried GOFLAGS, didn't work.

Also, adding -modfile to Run configuration might work for Running the program. But i'm more concerned with editing the right files. i.e. when I follow through on a symbol in the other module I want to be editing my local checked out copy of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, 2020.1.3 stable release, this is not supported. See [the related issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-9458) for future updates on this.